# It is oppressive for youths to have laws that prohibit something exclusive to them?

Tags: ethics, society, social-ethics

<sup>I don't belong to the group of youths, but one does not need to belong to the particular group in order to defend their interests, like in the case of animal rights movements. Also, I belonged to it, therefore I have some experiences.</sup>

Let us look on legal drinking age laws. I know why they exist, but these laws are easily overcome. I would say they are like obstacles rather than justifiable prohibitions. Yet, adults do not face such obstacles. It looks like  oppression to me.

There also are other examples such the driving age, the age of consent or age of watching porn. All of these appear oppressive by me. If you can drive well, your age is irrelevant. If you want to have sex, your age is irrelevant. If you want to watch porn, your age is irrelevant.

Is there an ethical theory that rejects such laws as oppressive ? If there is, what is its name or label ? I am looking for references.

---

I do not assume there are no differences between youths and adults, I just say this age difference is irrelevant, just as the difference between males and females is irrelevant when speaking about feminism (in the form of universal rights).

As [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/87565641.2016.1187033) says (link provided by @Conifold), adolescents on average are more impulsive, yet then we should merely to prohibit the driving for impulsive people, not for adolescents, why not? There indeed can be adolescents who are less impulsive than average adult. If it is wrong that these differences are foundations for these laws, then what are the arguments for existence of such laws?

Regarding sex, I assume informed consent is a much better solution than age of consent. Anyone, regardless of their age, can give consent if they know the potential results of sex: pregnancy, STDs, injury caused by too rough sex, etc.

Comment: Could you try to phrase questions differently than "is it ok for me to call something X and who else does it?", whether X is "oppression" or "natural". And you are factually mistaken about irrelevance of age to sex, drinking and driving due to risk taking/impulse control differences in children and adolescents.

Comment: @Conifold, have you read my last paragraph? These two questions should really be answered, others are somewhat rhetorical. Whether or not I'm mistaken is a matter of debate. You can also talk about the irrelevance of gender to particular kinds of labor, this does not mean feminism is wrong. Also, you ignore the premises: if one *drives well*, age is irrelevant - driving well includes driving as rules prescribe. Regarding sex - what do you suggest? It is intrinsic for humans. Also, if it is protected, what are the issues?

Comment: It is not a matter of debate, there are multiple empirical studies on it, here is a survey [Brain Development, Impulsivity, Risky Decision Making, and Cognitive Control](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/87565641.2016.1187033). As before, you need to do some prior research to come up with a good question rather than just channel what comes to mind.

Comment: @Conifold, have you read next sentence after I said it's the matter of debate? Do you assume I'm ignoring psychological and physiological differences between males and females? Indeed, there are such *on average* as well as in the case of youths compared to adults. But average does not mean universal. There are exceptions. But even then, how is brain development relevant to the right of drinking? Or how is it relevant to the right of having sex with anyone? The reason why age of consent exists is completely different: it is brought by feminists. Except in the case of Britain.

Comment: Writing more comments won't improve your post, focus on that instead, and the last one reads more like a rant.

Comment: Could you clarify whether your argument extends universally (i.e., if you are including four-year-olds in it), or whether "youths" implies an age bracket (and, if so, what is it and why).

Comment: @MishaR, don't you assume 4-year-old can pass driving test or have sexual drive, right? Then, out of given examples only drinking and watching porn are left. Such a kid would not intentionally seek porn as lacking sexual drive. Regarding drinking, no one argues here alcoholism is good. I should say that all the purposes (except of alcoholism) of drinking cannot be applied to such small children, they are not socialized enough. Maybe, 10-year-olds, but this is diff. story.

Comment: @rus9384 Why should the reason (such as sexual drive) matter? Perhaps it's merely curiosity. You seem to be avoiding the question, rather than giving a direct answer. In a situation where a small child expressed consent / wish to have sex, do you draw the line? And if a child of 6 passes a diving test, do you forbid them to drive? If yes, what is your cut-off point, and why.

Comment: For some things, I think you are actually looking at it backwards -- the problem with age cutoffs are not that youths are being unjustifiably obstructed, but that adults are being unjustifiably permitted.

Comment: @MishaR, I am not avoiding it: I am just stading in the position of realism. Cars are not designed for the child height. You may assume some kind of "4-year-old" who looks and acts like adult, but this is awkward. Anyway then I must argue that age is irrelevant. Whether a child can give informed consent is another thing, but hypothetically, if yes, then I must argue it's not wrong (if such a consent is given, which is implausible).

Comment: @Hurkyl, so, what do you mean? Are adults *unjustifiably* permitted to have sex? To drive after passing the test? To watch porn (not in the islamic countries)? So, who decides what is justifiable and what's not? People who are in power, who occasionally are adults. This situation is somehow resembling the situation when women didn't have many of mens rights exactly because they did not have power.

Comment: @rus9384 *Whether a child can give informed consent is another thing* - I disagree that it's another thing. It is a major part of the reasoning behind age restrictions. It is probably one of the main points you would need to argue against.

Comment: @MishaR, but 16 years? Come on, it's awkward. I have sexual desire since 11 and know of girls who had it since 9. And 4 year old can't understand consequences of sex, that's why [s]he can't give *informed* consent.

Comment: @rus9384 Well, ok, it doesn't have to be about sex, it's just that it forces a person to respond carefully :) What I'm saying is that the reason behind age restriction (driving, drinking, weapons, etc) tends to be rooted in the individuals *decision-making ability.* I would say that your argument might essentially boil down to this: at what age are our decision-making abilities good enough, and why are current ages too old. It might sound like a pain-in-the-ass argument, but, unless you include "9 is a valid age for consent / drinking" as part of your argument, you gotta deal with that.

Comment: @MishaR, the question is why age even is used for it? E.g. why driving test alone is not enough? Why not make somewhat exam about the awareness of consequences of drinking, having sex, etc, instead of using age? Of course, it is possible to find an analogy for *adults*: what would it be to replace illegality of heroine usage by exam about ones' awareness of consequnces of heroine usage? In my view, if a person knows about the consequences of heroine usage and still wants to use it, why not? Euthanasia should not be forbidden.

Comment: @rus9384 *"I would say they felt like..."*. So what? That you have a **feeling** about something is not an argument for very much. And it certainly is not much of an objection to something that has already gone through the public discourse, the legislative process and been codified since hundreds of years. Your feeling is recognised but other concerns have been deemed to be of higher priority than just your **feeling**.

Comment: @MichaelK, you misunderstood my thought. People are ready to act against the law, that's what matters. The same people are not ready to murder someone (even if they knew it wouldn't result in their punishment). So, completely healthy people act against the law.

Comment: @rus9384 I have a problem with your question then. This is because you say *"It seems as oppresion to me."* and then *"What ethics do state they are oppression?"*. That is dangerously close to asking for justification for a personal agenda. And in any case it does not change the fact that **you are very late to the party**. We know(!) that you feel this way. All youths, over all the world, over all the epochs, have always felt this way. We know that! Still we have made the judgement call: sorry, you have to be qualified to do some things, in spite of your feelings. See my answer below.

Comment: @MichaelK, then any question like "I think X, is there any philosophy stating X?" is a justification for a personal agenda, say, when X is solipsism. It is never late to the party: drugs were prohibited in all the western world, but now they are allowed in some of them.

Comment: @rus9384 We are having a constant discussion about what things are allowed and under what circumstances they allowed, and what and when they are not. But you are **extremely** late to the party in that the ethics that say "You need to be qualified to do something things; age may be a qualifier" are established and universally accepted since thousands of years. The concept of "coming of age", i.e. transitioning from being a child to being an adult, with the privileges and responsibilities that entails, is an integral part of global human culture and society.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80020/discussion-between-michaelk-and-rus9384).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be asking us to *do philosophy* (or perhaps respond to a personal philosophy?) rather than answer a question *about philosophy*

Comment: @virmaior, this question is not asking to do philosophy, but rather search it. This is the reason, why upvoted answer is upvoted and others - not. I can create own philosophy myself, it's not what I want from other people. I am asking about what already exists. Indeed, this is somewhat personal philosophy, but the question asks if there is accepted philosophy stating this.

Comment: In a single sentence, what is the question you have about philosophy here? It seems like the question is "what justifies having laws (as a proxy for moral standards) apply differently to people of different ages?"

Comment: If that's all, then I don't think it's a good fit here because the justification would vary depending on the social and political philosophy. Are we supposed to find one you like and then get upvoted for writing that way?

Comment: @virmaior, "what justifies" question alone is meaningless question, as there are too many opinions, this is too broad and doesn't belong to philosophy. Upvoted answer is upvoted not because I like it or somehow it gives agreement with my thoughts, but it provides useful information. I'm pretty sure, given enough power, arguments and the quality of wording of those arguments many things are justifiable (except some topics like right to kill just for fun).

Comment: @virmaior, but are there better arguments than "society merely decided to do so" or "because there is no better alternative"? It would be implausible that philosophy does not recognize the topic. So, there must be better arguments.

Comment: @Keelan, can you, please, explain, why is the question "What philosophy school [in academia] states X? How is it called?" is pushing a personal philosophy? I changed the wording but the meaning is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of political philosophy, here are three lines of consideration:

1. Libertarian political philosophy [could suggest](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/libertarianism/#AnaMinSta) that restrictions like driving ages and age of consent generally infringe on personal liberty.
2. Alternatively, age-based restrictions can be considered a form of age-based discrimination.
3. Finally, as you seem to suggest it's possible to argue that age-based restrictions serve as a biased or chauvinist proxy for other more relevant considerations.  For instance, we might consider granting a driving license to a child who has been properly trained and can pass a driving test.

The merits of 1 can be argued, but along those lines the issue would be having any requirements to drive rather than simply age-based ones.  However, this is one of the traditional ways of interpreting such restrictions as being oppressive.

For 2, substantial cognitive differences (such as those detailed in the paper on [adolescent brain development](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/87565641.2016.1187033)) between youths and adults, along with the social benefit of protecting the young from objective dangers suggests at least a prima facie justification for such restrictions.

I suppose 3 is interesting.  One response is simply that the benefits of removing those restrictions are minimal and carry risks.  One sort of risk comes from the imbalance of power that usually exists between adults and youths.  Restricting their access to situations where a serious dispute is likely to arise with an adult helps to discourage and protect them from coercive and abusive behaviors.  In ordinary situations, it's expected that a parent or guardian is able and willing to take care of their children in such a way that they don't need to engage in those sorts of risky interactions.

If you're interested in further exploring 3 and the parallels with universal rights and the historical treatment of women, you might find the topic of [feminist perspectives on disability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/feminism-disability/) to be relevant.

Comment: I am wondering how given paper is a counterargument for 2. Let's say that black people are worse in X, so, they should have different rights. Seems wrong, no? Or we can look at the castes in India: biological traits are heritable, so, castes are not wrong. In either case this question is yet alone that answers the first question.

Comment: The argument against 2 is that the restrictions have objective justification and are arguably in the interest of both the restricted group and society as a whole. Also biological development presumably happens over time. To instead use subjective criteria may introduce bias, while other objective criteria might favor certain groups with genetic or developmental advantages as MichaelK seems to suggest. You could still argue for 2 by e.g. claiming the harms to the restricted group outweigh the benefits or that age-based discrimination is never justified.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you for making this question plain and clear.  I agree that some of these rules seem pointless: for instance, clearly, any younger sibling is already watching restricted media when their older sibling is around.

But in the opposite extreme, consider what hazards exist in our civilization for which restricting by age is not nearly enough to protect the public.  Launching nuclear weapons, for instance, cannot be done by anyone but the most trusted members of government.  Should the ethical principle that ***people have freedom*** give every 9-year-old a shot at aiming a nuclear bomb?  Clearly not.

So what justifies these restrictions?  *We make laws to restrict things that require management in order to avoid harm.*  And the capability to manage risk is either demonstrated by **training** (as with a driver's license) or simply by **age.**

Sex is no exception.  Besides the possibility of transmitting diseases, sex does things to people's brains that nobody understands.  And the fact that sex causes new people to exist means that society has an interest in its restriction, so that fewer people get made vulnerable in this way.

Furthermore, Western governments intervene constantly in contractual relationships; so it's clear that the risks, costs and duration of pregnancy makes it sufficiently similar to a contract for the government to intervene in sexual relationships as well.

Finally, it would be really hard to say that these kinds of laws are oppression because they don't apply to people based on their permanent qualities but on a temporary situation that always goes away.

Comment: "Should the ethical principle that ***people have freedom*** give every 9-year-old a shot at aiming a nuclear bomb?" But ethical principles do not allow such freedom for every adult as well. "sex does things to people's brains that nobody understands." - the burden of proof is on those who claims. Do same things work for adults or not? If yes, then what's the point of restriction? Also, in many societies it's allowed for two youths to have sex with each other and it's even worse when the baby is born in such couple rather than one of parents is adult.

Comment: "it would be really hard to say that these kinds of laws are oppression because they don't apply to people based on their permanent qualities but on a temporary situation that always goes away." Then it's impossible to oppress old people by doing those things which are not considered to be oppression when done against mod-age people. It's impossible to oppress those people who are bedridden because of illness. There are many analogies.

Comment: Yes, the same things happen with adults.  The point of the age of consent law is that while no children below some age have seen enough to know what the risks are, at least most adults have seen enough and won't feel unjustly oppressed by the consequences of their liberty.

Comment: This is somewhat illogical. What are the sources for people to see enough if f.e.  watching porn is prohibited (yet another meaningless law, seen as obstacle)? I would argue for the idea of informed consent, regardless of age. It is not hard to know in 14 that STDs exist and that having sex results can result in pregnancy with no contraception. It's not hard to know some other important things at that age.

Comment: I think we don't have "informed consent" in the US because we acknowledge the risk that grown-ups would be able to deceive youngsters in order to take advantage of them.

Comment: If the youth is informed, how can [s]he be deceived? It is possible for 14-15 yo to have desire for sex, even for adult. If they had sex while adult was sleeping (yes, adult could not give consent), then youth gave consent, since there are no more agents. Then if we assume adult was not sleeping, not much changes: youth still could give consent.

Comment: I wasn't talking about deceit regarding what's covered in sex ed class, but deceit regarding the relationship itself.  It would be easy for a grown-up to make a kid believe that the relationship's commitment and power structure was in the kid's interest when in fact, it was not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79962/discussion-between-rus9384-and-elliot-svensson).

Comment: I would prefer not to go to chat.  If you prefer, you could take your next response and use it to re-forge your Question, and then I will read that and re-work my Answer.

Answer (score -2):

## Qualification

The ethics are quite simple:

- We find that for **some tasks** you need to be **qualified** to be allowed to do them. Because experience shows us that if we leave those tasks open for everyone, harm is likely to come to the individual, to the group and/or to society.

Qualification can be achieved in several ways:

- You can be certified by an appointed authority.

  Example: take a driver's test
- You can be vouched for by a trusted party.

  Example: "I know that person. They are cool, let them in".
- You can aquire some kind of attribute that automatically infers qualification.

  Example: you reach a certain age.

Now you may argue: so why not just qualify me in a different way? Let me **show** that I can do these things responsibly and without causing harm.

Two things speak against that:

- The cost and effort may be a lot higher, or even absurd for that type of qualification
- It may be considered unfair

On the first point... let us exemplify with the age of sexual consent. Do you really want to institute something that can qualify/disqualify kids to have sex before the age of consent? No, I did not think so... it would be absolutely absurd. Even though some people very clearly can have it before that age, and some should not have it even after the age of consent, the mere thought that qualification to be allowed to [copulate] should be done by some kind of **human review** instead of a certain age... that thought revolts our sensibilties.

On the second point, let us exemplify with voting, or in any other way participating in the democratic process. There are obvious problems with instituting a test to let people into the process. The risk of unfairness, and especially the impact of unfairness coming true, is so great that we have simply said: no tests, everyone can join in as soon as they have reached a certain age.

Comment: "It may be considered unfair" - joking? Qualification is much more fair mechanism than age restrictions. You attack me appealing to emotions: "it would be absolutely absurd."; "that thought revolts our sensibilties." Exactly unfairness rising from age restrictions made me think so. It's not the best way to heal diarea by putting plug in the arse. The source should be dealt with, not only the symptoms.

Comment: Not at all joking.

Comment: Unfounded statements like "it would be absolutely absurd" are on the same line with the fallacies of appealing to authority and emotion, which have no place on forums like the Philosophy Stack Exchange.